# If multiple answers work for a question, should all be voted on?

Tags: discussion, answers, up-votes

Should someone vote for multiple answers if they work for the specific question?

Comment: You can vote for multiple answers, but there is more to answers than just offering working solution. Some answers can be better than others because they offer explanations or other insights. If you have two working answers and one is significantly better than the other, then upvoting poorer answer is not usually justified. But it all depends on situation. You are not obliged to vote on anything.

Comment: The only criterion you should have when deciding where to vote on a post or not is pretty simple: "is this post useful for an unspecified future visitor?". If it is, vote up; if it is not - vote down, it's as simple as that, nothing else should come into considerstion (unless you lost your keys, of course). The same applies to multiple answers - evaluate each one *individually* and decide for yourself, but no one will force your hand if you just want to vote on one/several posts and skip the rest - it's up to you.

Answer (score 13):

Well, yes - it's good etiquette but not mandatory. In addition to rewarding the poster, it lets others know a post was useful

Answer (score 5):

If you think an answer is useful, then you can upvote it. Perhaps by giving more information, gives a good explanation, or for some other reason.

I probably won't upvote an answer if it is significantly newer then existing answers and doesn't provide any new information, or better explanations.

Answer (score 0):

> Should someone vote for multiple answers if they work for the specific question?

I don't vote for answers that I can't verify independently that it works for my specific question (which arguably is the same as the asker). If I go from the top scored and it doesn't work, then that's a downvote. If it works, then that's an upvote and stop reading then. Why should I continue evaluating posts after I found a solution to my problem?

Comment: Both the question and this answer seem a bit SO/programming-centric, on other sites in the network the Q&A may not be a problem with a solution that works or not, instead it can be a question with multiple valuable answers (while the question itself can still be clear and focused). Moreover, the usefulness of each answer can be judged just from reading those answers without further evaluation. And even on technical sites this is often possible when the answerer presents the results of their code and/or a clear explanation.

Comment: As for "why continue after I found a solution": because other solutions may be more useful in specific cases and the top-voted answer provides only the general case. Made-up example in Python: Q: how do I generate a range between x and y? A1: `range(x,y)`. A2, with fewer votes: in the special case that x=0 you can also do `range(y)`.