# What is the [multiple-answers] tag for?

Tags: discussion, tags, meta

The [tag wiki excerpt](https://meta.stackexchange.com/tags/multiple-answers/info) for [multiple-answers](/questions/tagged/multiple-answers) says:

> For questions about situations where a single user posts multiple answers to a single question.

However, there are quite a few places it is used for the general situation of having multiple answers to a single question, *regardless of whether a single user posted them* or not. (It's also used for when a single user is considering posting multiple answers but hasn't yet, but that seems more relevant to the current excerpt wording.) For example,

- [If multiple answers work for a question, should all be voted on?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/376589/) - a recent question edited to have the [multiple-answers](/questions/tagged/multiple-answers) tag instead of the [answers](/questions/tagged/answers) tag
- [Answer count on feed items is wrong](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/317794/) - using the tag to report a failure of the answer count to update when a new answer was posted
- [Which answer should I accept](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/216655/) - using the tag to talk about a situation where two answers were posted to the same question, by different users

It's probably also worth mentioning that this is a rarely-used tag, especially recently. There are 32 questions total, with 2 from this year, 0 from 2021, 1 from 2020, and 1 from 2019.

Is the [multiple-answers](/questions/tagged/multiple-answers) tag meant for cases when the multiple answers were posted *by a single user* only, or for when there are multiple answers, period? In the latter case, does the excerpt need an update? In the former case, does the tag need a rename? The tag's name doesn't suggest the limitation placed upon it by the excerpt, which is probably how it accumulated questions using it for the general case.

Comment: I'd say we should stick with its current excerpt. All other uses can make use of the answers tag.

Comment: I reverted the edit to the first question, on the basis of the current tag definition.

Answer (score 6):

To avoid confusion I propose that the [multiple-answers](/questions/tagged/multiple-answers) tag be merged with the [answers](/questions/tagged/answers) tag while leaving the former as a synonym of the latter.

I think this would be reasonable to do given that it is used so rarely and sometimes misused.

Comment: I'd argue it's a useful tag to have separate. As an example, questions about the prompt that shows to users when they try to add an additional answer to a question they've answered would use this tag.